# How do I add TF2 to Steam library?

Tags: team-fortress-2

When I click on play now on Team Fortress 2 in Steam, nothing happens.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled steam on my computer, still nothing.  It won't even add it to my steam account.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to steam.  This will work in the Steam client or your browser, but it may be easier to follow the instructions in a web browser.
2. Go to [TF2's store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/440/)
3. Click `Play Game` where would normally you would `Add to Cart`: [image: tf2 store]

Now TF2 will be in your Steam library and you should be able to find it in your list of games and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Community hub, search for "Team Fortress 2". Look through the contents and hover over player's profile to see who is playing TF2 right now. If you found someone visit their profile and click on "Join Game".
Steam should prompt you the following.
[image: Team Fortress 2 Install]